# for loop and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

How do I populate some text with a paragraph using innerHTML? I need to enter a number into the textbox and then repeat some text as many times as the number entered into the textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ex10.js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input-type" onKeyUp="myFunction()">
    <p id="sample-text">Here is some text</p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            let count = document.getElementById("input-type").value;
            document.getElementById("sample-text").innerHTML = count;

            if (isNaN(count)) {
                document.getElementById("sample-text").innerHTML = "Error. Not a number";
            }
            else {
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("sample-text").innerHTML = "This is some text";
                }

            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `int i` isn’t JavaScript (no static types, no real relation to Java); did you mean `let i` or `var i`?

Comment: my bad more used to c++ and java

Answer (score 6):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ex10.js</title>
<script>
     function myFunction() {
        var count = document.getElementById("input-type").value;


        if (isNaN(count)) {
            document.getElementById("sample-text").innerHTML = "Error. Not a number";
        }
        else {
             // create your empty array
        var lines = "";

        // loop x amount of times and add your text to the array
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            lines = lines+"Atmiya\n";
        }

        // convert the array to a string, with each string on its own line
        document.getElementById("sample-text").innerHTML = lines;
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="input-type" onKeyUp="myFunction()">
    <p id="sample-text">Here is some text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("sample-text").innerHTML = someVar;
```

This will completely overwrite the content of your html element every time you call it, which is probably your problem.

What you'll want to do instead is build your string beforehand, and then populate the element once afterwards. How about building an array, and then creating a string using `join`?

```
// create your empty array
var lines = [];

// loop x amount of times and add your text to the array
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    lines.push("This is some text");
}

// convert the array to a string, with each string on its own line
document.getElementById("sample-text").innerHTML = lines.join("\n");
```

Comment: is there anyway to do it without the use of arrays

Comment: Why do you not want to use arrays? Seems like a good use case for an array.

Comment: If you insist though, you can build a string with `var str = ""` and then `str += "some text"` within your loop.

Comment: just wondering if it is possible, you do not have to show me, a simple yes or no will suffice

Comment: Just trying to help you out. I hope my suggestions pointed you in the right direction :)

Comment: absolutely and i did not mean to sound ungrateful, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tricks to make it easier:

[<input type="number">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

> <input> elements of type "number" are used to let the user enter a number. They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries. The browser may opt to provide stepper arrows to let the user increase and decrease the value using their mouse or by simply tapping with a fingertip.

You can also use the `+=` operator to concatenate to an element's `innerHTML` property.

`onchange` is probably better to use than `onkeyup`. I'm not sure `onkeyup` works with a touch screen. And the number input box has little controls to change the value.

```js
function go() {
  let text = document.querySelector('#sample-text').innerHTML;
  let times = document.querySelector('#times').value;
  let output = document.querySelector('#output');
  let ix = 0;

  output.innerHTML = '';

  while (ix < times) {
    output.innerHTML += text;
    ix++;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" id="times" onchange="go()">
<p id="sample-text">Here is some text</p>
<p id="output"></p>
```